# How to build wxWidgets 2.9.1 with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wxwidgets

I have a freshly downloaded Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express and wxWidgets 2.9.1. The build folder under wx\build\msw has solution files for VC++ versions 6 through 9 (2008).

I tried to open the latest solution, wx_vc9.sln. It converted all the projects with a bunch of warnings. When I try to build every project gets the error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5):
>   error MSB6001: Invalid command line
>   switch for "cmd.exe". The path is not
>   of a legal form.

Trying to open the previous version of the solution, wx_vc8.sln, generates the same conversion warnings and the same build errors.

I Googled for some hints and found a suggestion to start with the .dsw file.  I opened wx.dsw and it generated an error for each of the project files:

> D:\3rdParty\wx\build\msw\wx_wxregex.dsp
>   : error  : Project upgrade failed.

Finally in desperation I tried `nmake /f makefile.vc` and was greeted with yet another error:

> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' :
>   return code '0xc0000135'

Anybody have any hints?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of solving this, firstly if you update to a more recent version of the wxWidgets SVN trunk this is fixed (and so it will be fixed in 2.9.2 when it is released). If you don't want to work from trunk of wait for 2.9.2 then if you do a find and replace over all .vcxproj files and replace

> >$(INTDIR) $(OUTDIR);%(AdditionalInputs)

with

> >%(FullPath);%(AdditionalInputs)

it should then compile fine.

Comment: Did the edits. Got lots of warnings, but no errors! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, trust me people, avoid all nonsense and start up your **Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt** and navigate to **[wxwidgets directory]\build\msw** 
Then compile using the makefile with the following command :

**nmake -f makefile.vc BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=0 SHARED=0 UNICODE=1**

Of course change the options as needed.
You will be saving a lot of trouble this way, this is the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

The Key to Compilation using Visual C++ 2010 Express and wxWidgets 2.9.3 is to keep Pressing F7 Again-and-Again-and-again.... till you you get '0 Failed' Message below. Because many Projects have dependencies which are not satisfied immediately, so it is necessary to keep compiling with 'F7' till all are satisfied.

Download wxWidgets. I downloaded the .7-Zip File (only 12 MB ! ), and installed it at C:\wxWidgets The Structure should be like so that you see the following Folders like C:\wxWidgets\lib and C:\wxWidgets\build etc etc...

Basically the process should be to go to C:\wxWidgets\build\msw , and open wx_vc9 Solution File for VC-2008, and convert it to VC-2010 when asked. Then Choose 'DLL-Release Win32' on Top, and Press F7. Wait for Compilation to take place and see the Message. Then keep Pressing F7 again and again till you get '0 Failed' Message below. Then you would want to Compile 'DLL-Debug' Release in the same manner.

The compiled DLL Files can then be found at C:\wxWidgets\lib\vc_dll.  Now, To Add vc_dll Folder to your PATH, Right-Click on My-Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment-Variables -> User-Variables. Search for 'Path' -> 'Edit', and then Just Append ;C:\wxWidgets\lib\vc_dll to the End.

This makes running your compiled Application easier, as your .EXE can now easily find DLLs.
When you are packaging, then you obviously need to bundle specific Release-DLL'S along.

Then you can compile the Samples located at C:\wxWidgets\samples.
I just go to individual Project Folder, like for e.g. C:\wxWidgets\samples\drawing, and Open drawing_vc9 Project, then Convert it as Prompted, and then hit F7 to create Release Version. Now if you go inside C:\wxWidgets\samples\drawing\vc_mswudll\ Folder, you have your 'drawing.exe' ready-to-be-run !

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

Use the wx.dsw, took me a while to finally get it but it'll build fine after that. I also suggest using one of the sample projects such as 'minimal' as the base and just fix all the config paths to match what you want to build (as manually setting up I encountered issues).

If you already used the wx_vc9 (like you said you did) you are probably best off just deleting all of wx and restarting with it and using wx.dsw like I said above.

Comment: I tried deleting everything and starting over, as you suggested. Still getting an error on each .dsp file - `Project upgrade failed.` I believe there was a recent service pack to Visual Studio which might be making the difference.